# UIButton not updating state (Selected/Default) dynamically when disconnected from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a UIButton set that works great, but only when connected to the Xcode (both in a running simulator and a connected iPhone).

If I am running the simulator, the selected button will be the only one selected

If I 'stop' the simulator, any button that has been selected will remain in the selected UI state, even when the code is specifically marking it as deselected.

I'm not sure what could be making that change, and why it works when the simulator is connected (and I can see logs, inconveniently).

Here's the code I'm using to update the button's state (I have connected the images using 'Button Background Image' in the storyboard

```
        if format == "A" {
            button1.isSelected = true
            button2.isSelected = false
            button3.isSelected = false
        } else if format == "B" {
            button1.isSelected = false
            button2.isSelected = true
            button3.isSelected = false
        } else {
            button1.isSelected = false
            button2.isSelected = false
            button3.isSelected = true
        }
```

*I'm not sure if it should also be mentioned, but some nuances I've noticed in trying to fix it:

- The images I used are PNG, with transparent backgrounds
- Using those transparent images, when a UIButton is deselected, the entire button turns white (again, only when disconnected from Xcode... when I'm connected to Xcode it works flawlessly as expected)
- If I change the images and add a background, then when the button is deselected, it still uses the 'Selected' image

Here's a quick video of what is happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pcl8lpkbgcr9l5/Example%20Issue.mov?dl=0  (First half is with simulator connected to Xcode, second half is after I stopped the xcode run)

Comment: Can you please make a demo video and post here?

Comment: @Kudos As requested: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pcl8lpkbgcr9l5/Example%20Issue.mov?dl=0 (First half is with simulator connected to Xcode, second half is after I stopped the xcode run)

Comment: Are you changing the background color of buttton on selected/Default state?

Comment: @Kudos no, the only thing that should be changing is the Background Image of the UIButton

Comment: You are doing wrong. Button State doesn't work for bgimage but for Button image.

Comment: Thanks @Kudos! It is working for me to change the background button on UIButton state change (as long as simulator is connected to Xcode), so not sure what you mean by this...

Comment: @Kudos I also updated all of them to use 'image' instead of 'bgimage' and the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you build the source code but I did a simple example similar to the video you provided above.

```
import UIKit
class DemoViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupButton()
    }
    
    func setupButton() {
        // Setup image for the buttons
        self.button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "book"), for: .normal)
        self.button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "headphone"), for: .normal)
        self.button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "img"), for: .normal)
        
        // setup background image for the buttons in the selected state
        // In normal the buttons do not have a background image
        self.button1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg"), for: .selected)
        self.button2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg"), for: .selected)
        self.button3.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg"), for: .selected)
        
        // setup target action for the buttons
        self.button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.button1.isSelected = true // set default value for the button
    }
    
    
    @objc func showDetail(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // When user touch on the button then all buttons should be unselected
        // Then the target button should be selected
        button1.isSelected = false
        button2.isSelected = false
        button3.isSelected = false
        sender.isSelected = true
        var format = "";
        switch sender {
        case button1:
            format = "A"
        case button2:
            format = "B"
        default:
            format = "C"
        }
        
        // Show the detail screen
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: format)
    }
    
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
            vc.format = sender as! String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Have you seen a similar issue where it works well with a running simulator, but not when the simulator is detached?

Comment: I am confused, I don't know what you implement in source code. Or may you provide us the source code was be an error, maybe we can investigate more your problem? If you did like my example but it still does not work then I think the root cause is in another place.

Comment: @Diggory I think he is trying to change bg of Button on the basis of State change. But This only works on Button image change not bgImage change

Comment: @Kudos -:)) I don't know where his problem is in the source code. I just watched his video and made an example like expect he say above.
Because The button has 4 basic states you know: default (normal), highlighted, selected, disabled. In each state, you can set the image or image background for it. And in the source code control, you just set the correct state for the button and that is it.

Comment: @Diggory Thanks for helping! Unfortunately this is almost exactly the same implementation I already have (if you see the video, you can see that I've got it successfully working in the case of the simulator attached) so it doesn't quite solve my problem

Comment: @JFed8 Here is a video of my source code. The First 17 seconds are running from the Xcode tool. For the rest, I disconnected the Xcode and run it manually. And I see the button status update correctly.
https://streamable.com/bqyfcr

Comment: @Diggory thanks for sending the video! I implemented the code as you described above, but the problem was unsolved. I have resorted to simply not using the 'selected' state at all, and simple overwriting the .normal state button image each time the button is selected. Thank you for your contributions!